# Getting count() of class static array

Tags: php, arrays, static-members

Is it possible to get the count of a class defined static array? For example:

```
class Model_Example
{

    const VALUE_1 = 1;
    const VALUE_2 = 2;
    const VALUE_3 = 3;

    public static $value_array = array(
        self::VALUE_1 => 'boing',
        self::VALUE_2 => 'boingboing',
        self::VALUE_3 => 'boingboingboing',
    );

    public function countit()
    {
        // count number
        $total = count(self::$value_array );
        echo ': ';
        die($total);
    }
}
```

At the moment calling the countit() method returns `:`

Comment: Works fine here http://codepad.org/XfFhv5FP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The problem in the code above is the die() function. If the param to die() is an integer, it will being used as the exit value of the script and not printed to the screen.

change the countit() method to :

```
public function countit()
{
    // count number
    $total = count(self::$value_array );
    echo ': ', $total;
}
```

You will find more info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)

Comment: I was using the die as a dirty-debug :)